# TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using jumbo 4.1.1 template. I get the response, but this error occurs.
My code is below:
authAction.js:

```
...
export const userSignIn = (user) => {
// const {email, password} = user;
console.log(user)
axios.post(base_url +'login', user)
.then(response=> {
    console.log(response.data)
    return {
        type: SIGNIN_USER,
        payload: user
    };
})    
};
```

But when I run the project, I got the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`
[image]

Comment: `userSignIn` isn't returning anything

Answer (score 2):

I believe that is because you have not dispatched the action properly.

Are you using thunk?

If you are using Redux and making an async call, you should return dispatch.

```js
const userSignup = (signupData) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      let res = await axios.post(`${url}/user/`, { user: signupData });
      dispatch({
        type: "FETCH_CURRENT_USER_SUCCESS",
        payload: res.data.user,
      });

      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(
        "%c CATCH in userSignup ",
        "background: red; color: #bada55",
        error
      );
    }
  };
};
```

Notice, that I am returning a function with dispatch as an argument in the second line. and then using that `dispatch` (4th line) that dispatches the action's type and payload.

Also I'm returning something from the function userSignUp, finally, so the invoker of the function `userSignUp` gets something in response.

If you don't understand anything above, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could benefit from using async + await here.

For example:

```js
export const userSignIn = async (user) => {
    try {
        // const {email, password} = user;
        console.log(user);
        const data = await axios.post(base_url +'login', user);     
        console.log(data);
        return {
            type: SIGNIN_USER,
            payload: user,
        }; 
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        // return an error action...?
        return {
            type: ERROR,
            payload: error,
        };
    }
};
```